# What do I wrong comparing a tuple of integers in PureScript?

Tags: javascript, integer, trace, purescript, unless

Debugging my event handler for the mouse move event, I wrote this code:

```
 unless (scrollDelta == Tuple 0 0) $ trace (show scrollDelta) \_ -> do ...
```

And I get console output

```
Tuple 0 0
```

The idea behind this is to save a difference in the mouse position whenever the user moves the mouse with the first mouse button pressed.

Is this a compiler bug?

My workaround is to change the type of `scrollDelta` to `Maybe (Tuple Int Int)` where `Nothing` represents "no mouse movement while button pressed" instead of `Tuple 0 0`, which works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the difference between *evaluation* and *execution*.

When you write something like:

```
Console.log "foo"
```

contrary to your intuition, that does *not* actually print anything to console. Instead, this creates an "action", which has to be "executed" at some later point, and it's only then that it will print something to the console.

Conversely, same action can actually be "executed" several times, and thus produce multiple effects:

```
printFoo = Console.log "foo"
-- ^ Nothing is printed at this point

main = do
    printFoo
    printFoo
    printFoo
    -- ^ "foo" is printed three times
```

- "Evaluation" is creating the "action"
- "Execution" is running the "action" in order to produce whatever effects it produces

In the above example, evaluation happens once, but execution - three times.

---

The way `unless` works, it takes a `Boolean` value and an "action", and it returns *another "action"*:

```
dontPrintFoo = unless true printFoo
```

When you execute the action `dontPrintFoo`, it will be the action returned by `unless`, which will examine the `Boolean` parameter and choose *not to* execute the action `printFoo`.

But say you have a bit more complicated scenario:

```
dontPrintFoo = unless true $ if qux then printFoo else printBar
```

Here, both parameters of `unless` must be "evaluated" (but not "executed"!) before they are passed to `unless`. This means that the value of `qux` and the result of `if`/`then` is calculated *before* calling `unless`. But the resulting action would be executed later, when the whole result is called from `main`.

---

But `trace` is special. Magic. Even though it produces an effect (printing to console), the compiler thinks it's a pure function. Like `2 + 3` or like `if qux then foo else bar`.  It's done this way for debugging convenience: so that you can insert tracing in pure, non-effectful code.

This means that `trace` is evaluated at "evaluation" time, not "execution". Which means that it's evaluated *before* `unless` is even called, and therefore it's evaluated regardless of whether the `Boolean` parameter is `true` or `false`.

---

If you want the tracing to only work when `unless` decided to execute the action, try `traceM`:

```
unless (...) do
    traceM (show scrollDelta)
    foo
    bar
```

Comment: thanks. I hate when I get paranoid starring at my code ... but of course, in general I am aware of the distinction between execution and evaluation. It all makes sense now.